# pull data from json array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using the following script to pull deals from groupon's api and place them in my html page, but I'm not able to pull the data from the json file thats in an array or loop or whatever it is

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://api.groupon.com/v2/deals.json?callback=?", 
    {
        client_id: "b252ad3634a4ab2985b79d230ccc4e49a3ea9d19",
        show: "all",
        division_id: "los-angeles"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    // do whatever processing you need to do to the data
    // right here, then drop it in the div
    $.each(data.deals, function (i, v) {
        $img = $("<img/>", {
            src: v.mediumImageUrl
        });
        $title = $("<div/>", {
            html: v.title,
            class: "dealName"
        });
        $price = $("<div/>", {
            html: v.options.price,
            class: "price"
        });
        $deal = $("<div/>", {
            html: v.textAd,
            class: "dealSmall"
        });
        $(".deals").append($deal);
         $deal.prepend($img,$title,$price);

    });
});
});
```

I need to grab the price which is inside options, thanks in advance

Json Data

```
{
"deals":  [
    {
        "type": "groupon",
        "textAd":  {
            "headline": "",
            "line2": "",
            "line1": ""
        },
        "finePrint": "Limit 1 per household, may buy 5 additional as gifts. Must activate by expiration date on Groupon, membership expires 12 months from activation date. Online redemption required. New clients only. Must be 18 or older. Must use promotional value in 1 visit.",
        "smallImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/bv8yY9tnX1mTwddFDRN/fJ-440x267/v1/t50x50.jpg",
        "locationNote": "",
        "isMerchandisingDeal": false,
        "division":  {
            "timezoneOffsetInSeconds": -25200,
            "lng": -118.243,
            "timezoneIdentifier": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "name": "Los Angeles",
            "lat": 34.0522,
            "id": "los-angeles",
            "timezone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
        },
        "status": "open",
        "soldQuantityMessage": "80+",
        "limitedQuantityRemaining": null,
        "grouponRating": null,
        "grid4ImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/bv8yY9tnX1mTwddFDRN/fJ-440x267/v1/t300x182.jpg",
        "vip": "",
        "salesforceLink": "https://login.salesforce.com/006C000000jiCfiIAE",
        "areas":  [
            {
                "name": "Los Angeles",
                "id": "los-angeles"
            },
            {
                "name": "San Gabriel Valley",
                "id": "san-gabriel-valley"
            },
            {
                "name": "San Fernando Valley",
                "id": "san-fernando-valley"
            }
        ],
        "mediumImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/bv8yY9tnX1mTwddFDRN/fJ-440x267/v1/t100x100.jpg",
        "tippingPoint": 0,
        "highlightsHtml": "<p>Members snag pairs of free tickets at whim from a database of concert, theater, museum, and sporting events that haven't yet sold out</p>",
        "dealTypes":  [
            {
                "description": "Live sports, music, and theater events",
                "name": "Will Call",
                "id": "will-call"
            }
        ],
        "announcementTitle": "Half Off Event-Access Membership for Two",
        "title": "$40 for a One-Year Event-Access Membership for Two from Fillaseat ($79.95 Value)",
        "isNowDeal": false,
        "tippedAt": "2013-08-13T07:12:31Z",
        "startAt": "2013-08-14T07:00:00Z",
        "pitchHtml": "<p>Seeing a live performance is an exciting, ever-changing interaction between you, the performer, and the stranger whose lighter you keep stealing. Make connections with this Groupon.</p>\n\n<h4>$40 for a One-Year Event-Access Membership for Two ($79.95 Value)</h4>\n\n<p>A one-year membership provides twosomes with free seats at Los Angeles shows, concerts, and sporting events that have not yet sold out. Tickets can be claimed on a first-come, first-served basis—members simply visit the website to browse available events and, once they've selected an event they'd like to attend, they'll reserve a pair of tickets. Members can expect to find several events available each week, and are welcome to reserve up to two tickets for every posted event. See the <a href="http://www.fillaseatla.com/memrule.php">full list of rules</a> that apply to members.<p></p>",
        "isOptionListComplete": true,
        "channels":  [],
        "accessType": "featured",
        "grid6ImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/bv8yY9tnX1mTwddFDRN/fJ-440x267/v1/t460x279.jpg",
        "says":  {
            "websiteContent": "<div style="margin-top: -30px">\r\n<img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/images/humor_service/groupon_says/gizmos/email-gizmo-image-1376335702-DEM_Umami.jpg" alt="Umami" />\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n",
            "emailContent": "Which foods taste like an anti-sweet, salty tongue-treat? Click here to find out. ",
            "title": "Umami",
            "websiteContentHtml": "<div style="margin-top: -30px">\n<img src="http://s3.grouponcdn.com/images/humor_service/groupon_says/gizmos/email-gizmo-image-1376335702-DEM_Umami.jpg" alt="Umami" />\n</div>\n\n\n",
            "emailContentHtml": "<p>Which foods taste like an anti-sweet, salty tongue-treat? Click here to find out.</p>",
            "id": "umami"
        },
        "merchant":  {
            "websiteUrl": "http://www.fillaseatla.com",
            "ratings":  [],
            "name": "Fillaseat",
            "id": "fillaseat-la"
        },
        "isTipped": true,
        "endAt": "2013-08-19T06:59:59Z",
        "dealUrl": "http://www.groupon.com/deals/fillaseat-la-2",
        "sidebarImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/bv8yY9tnX1mTwddFDRN/fJ-440x267/v1/t200x300.jpg",
        "displayOptions":  [
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "timer"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "quantity"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "discount"
            }
        ],
        "placementPriority": "nearby",
        "uuid": "f4c72216-fddd-11e2-8117-0025906a929e",
        "tags":  [
            {
                "name": "Arts and Entertainment"
            }
        ],
        "soldQuantity": 80,
        "shippingAddressRequired": false,
        "isTravelBookableDeal": false,
        "placeholderUrl": "https://secure-assets.grouponcdn.com/images/groupon/grayPlaceholder.png",
        "id": "fillaseat-la-2",
        "redemptionLocation": "Online Deal",
        "options":  [
            {
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/fillaseat-la-2/confirmation?pledge_id=7994510",
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 6,
                "discountPercent": 50,
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "80+",
                "price":  {
                    "formattedAmount": "$40.00",
                    "amount": 4000,
                    "currencyCode": "USD"
                },
                "externalUrl": null,
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "value":  {
                    "formattedAmount": "$79.95",
                    "amount": 7995,
                    "currencyCode": "USD"
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "title": "One duet membership",
                "redemptionLocations":  [],
                "specificAttributes":  {},
                "details":  [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 1 per household, may buy 5 additional as gifts. Must activate by expiration date on Groupon, membership expires 12 months from activation date. Online redemption required. New clients only. Must be 18 or older. Must use promotional value in 1 visit."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "endAt": "2013-08-19T06:59:59Z",
                "discount":  {
                    "formattedAmount": "$39.95",
                    "amount": 3995,
                    "currencyCode": "USD"
                },
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "customFields":  [],
                "soldQuantity": 80,
                "expiresAt": "2013-11-14T07:59:59Z",
                "id": 7994510,
                "isSoldOut": false
            }
        ],
        "isSoldOut": false,
        "isAutoRefundEnabled": false,
        "shortAnnouncementTitle": "Event-Access Membership for Two",
        "largeImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/bv8yY9tnX1mTwddFDRN/fJ-440x267/v1/t440x300.jpg"
    },
```

Comment: what does options contain?

Comment: We could you easier if you could provide an example of the data.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hvjc2/

Comment: it seems to be working and showing price. What is your problem here?

Comment: price isnt showing up, some people put the price in the title but i need price in its own div, also, how do i surrond the img with a div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options` is an array, and `price` is also an object:

```
"price":{
    "formattedAmount":"$40.00",
    "amount":4000,
    "currencyCode":"USD"
},
```

This works, though I think you may need to have more iterations to show all the options, if there's more than one:

```
html: v.options[0].price.formattedAmount,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WNd4r/

Comment: thanks, its working, also, how can i surrond the img with a div that has it's own class name ?

Comment: Change the part where you create the image to create a div and append the image to it.

Comment: so i change the img/ to div/ ? not very good with this stuff, new to api's and json, thanks for you help, really appreciated

Comment: You would change it to something like `$img = $('<div/>', {[set attributes here]}).append([existing img creation code]);`

Comment: dont know what attributes to use

Comment: I don't know either. It's your code. Look at the other lines, where they set the html and class. You should be able to figure out what you want.